# nested_form and twitter typeahead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-typeahead

I have implemented nested_form gem and twitter type ahead in my app. But I can not get the typeahead to work on the dynamically added fields.

My line that adds the dynamic lines is 
    <%= ff.link_to_add t("add_author"), :book_authors, :data => { :target => "#authors"} %>

And The JS for the typeahead of the first line is:

```
$(function(){
  var authors = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('author'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
      url: '/load_suggestions?q=%QUERY',
      filter: function(list) {
        return $.map(list, function(author) { return {author: book }; });
      }
    }
  });

  authors.initialize();

  $('#load_suggestions').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
  },
  {
      name: 'authors',
      displayKey: 'author',

      source: authors.ttAdapter()
  });
});
```

How do I modify the above to work for the dynamically added lines? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for click events and activate typeahed after field was added., 
handling javascript events is given in the README of nested_form gem.

e.g.

```
 $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
      // this field was just inserted into your form
      var field = event.field; 
      field.typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
      },
      {
         name: 'authors',
         displayKey: 'author',

         source: authors.ttAdapter()
     });
});
```

Comment: Let me give it a try and I will get back. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi there, I have it working on normal pages but it doesn't work on bootstrap-modal. Any suggestions for modals? Thanks